# Few questions about Turing machines.

Tags: computer-science

i started to college about computer sciences this year and i have few questions about Turing Machines. I will be very glad if you answer. Sorry for my bad English if i have mistake.

Can Turing machines recognize irregular languages ?

Are Turing machines more powerful computational model than inverse automata (PDA)?

Are there more Turing-recognizable languages than Turing-decidable languages ?

Can inverse automata (PDAs) recognize all context-free languages (CFL)

Comment: Welcome to MSE ^_^. What have you tried? Do you have ideas of your own? Once we have a better idea of exactly where you're stuck we can help you better

Comment: I'm just researching and couldn't find the answers on the internet

Comment: Can somebody help please ?